# Check if class is equal swift

Tags: swift

I have a class where I have an extension to check equality but on test, the equality crashes.

here's my code

```
extension LPItemAction {
    public override func isEqual(_ other: Any?) -> Bool {
        if (other as? LPItemAction) == self {
            return true
        } else if !(other is LPItemAction) {
            return false
        } else {
            let otherAction = other as? LPItemAction
            return hash == otherAction?.hash
        }
    }
}
```

and my test case is like this

```
func testIsEqualSelf() {
        // Given
        let action = LPItemAction()
        action.type = .account
        
        // When
        let equal = action.isEqual(action)
        
        // Then
        XCTAssertTrue(equal)
    }
```

I got a crash with error `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16e747fc0)`

Comment: comparing hash does not make much sense. Comparing with `Any` does not make sense. This is not java. Just make the type `Equatable`. `==` is not pointer comparison like in Java. `==` on `NSObject` actually delegates to `isEqual` therefore your first line creates an infinite recursion, ending sooner or later in a stack overflow.

Comment: This isn't the cause of your crash, but don't implement an isEqual function. Have your class conform to the `Equatable` protocol. (That's what it's for. When you do that, you can use the `==` operator to compare instances of your class..

Comment: @DuncanC On `NSObject` this is actually the source of the crash, if you use `==` within `isEqual`.

Comment: @Sulthan what am I supposed to use?

Answer (score 1):

Since this is obviously a `NSObject`, you are probably right to override `isEqual`. There are some rules though.

You cannot use `==`. This operator invokes the `Equality` protocol, which, on `NSObject` is implemented using `isEqual`, therefore you end up with infinite recursion.

Another thing is that using `hash` to compare equality is just wrong.

```
// test type first
guard let otherAction = other as? LPItemAction else {
   return false
}

// test reference equality
if self === otherAction {
  return true
}

// test equality of all properties
return type === otherAction.type
```

Comment: Equality => Equatable ?